# Distributed Solr 3.5 search aborts

Tags: solr, solrj

**My question**

How can I export (many up to ~30'000'000) solr documents to csv in a sharded setup using distributed query (solrj)?

My strategy is to query in batches (n Days) but I currently reach a limitation of ~200'000 documents per batch.

I would like to be able to fetch 1'000'000 per batch.

My setup is a solr index with multiple shards. Each shard holds documents of a month. The documents are added to the shards based on a timestamp field. I query with the shards parameter set and this usually works well.

Now I want to export the documents or just some fields into a csv file. But with many documents my request fails. I stripped down my url and got this request failing:

```
// query I) query march 2013 sharded -> does not work

http://localhost:8080/index/in.part.201301/select/?rows=1000000&
shards=localhost:8080/index/in.part.201303&
wt=csv&
fl=id&
q=firstTimestamp_dis:[2013-03-01T00:00:00Z+TO+2013-04-01T00:00:00Z]&
version=2.2
```

Exception on the index server:

```
14:18:55,726 SEVERE [SolrCore] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:33)
    at org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:80)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:142)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:101)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1372)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:356)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:252)
    at com.company.InitializerDispatchFilter.doFilter(InitializerDispatchFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

19:16:44,638 INFO  [SolrCore] [in1.part.201303] webapp=/index path=/select params={} status=500 QTime=2 
19:16:44,647 SEVERE [SolrCore] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

request: http://localhost:8080/ipc-index/in1.part.201303/select
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:432)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpCommComponent$1.call(SearchHandler.java:421)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpCommComponent$1.call(SearchHandler.java:393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

A non shard query works:

```
// query II) query march 2013 non sharded --> works
http://localhost:8080/index/in.part.201303/select/?rows=1000000&
fl=id&
q=firstTimestamp_dis:[2013-03-01T00:00:00Z+TO+2013-04-01T00:00:00Z]&
version=2.2&
wt=csv
```

and

```
// query III) sharded query with rows=200000 --> works as well, (rows=210000 does fail like query I)
http://localhost:8080/index/in.part.201301/select/?rows=200000&
fl=id&
q=firstTimestamp_dis:[2013-03-01T00:00:00Z+TO+2013-04-01T00:00:00Z]&
version=2.2&
wt=csv&
shards=localhost:8080/index/in.part.201303
```

**Memory**
I don't think the problem is memory related: My index server vm has 1GB memory if I reduce the memory to 256MB and execute query III) it will execute very slow and abort with out of memory. If I increase the memory query I) will still fail.

Also if I add more fields to the field list with query III) it will always succeed.

On my client (slorj) I use Method.POST to send the query.

Can anyone help please?